# I want to post video with custom text on Facebook wall using my iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, video

I have followed the Facebook documentation for video post with message.

The sample code is as follows:

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];

NSData *videodata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString];

NSURL *imgUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"jpg"]];

NSData *imagedata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"source": videodata,
                         @"thumb": imagedata,
                         @"description":@"#BHARAT",
                         };
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"videos"
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
    NSLog(@" Result-%@",result);
    NSLog(@"Error=%@",error);
}];
```

**But it gives me the error as follows**

> Error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x16547ac0 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An unknown error has occurred., NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKTemporaryErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x16555040>, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=1, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=1, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 1;
>               message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 500;
>   }, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
>       OK
>   ), NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The server is temporarily busy, please try again.}

Please provide me the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

try to use code below

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
      NSURL *urlString = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];

      FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
      video.videoURL = videoURL;
      FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
      content.video = video;
      ...

      // Assuming self implements <FBSDKSharingDelegate>
      [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
    }
```

note: Video should be less the 12 MB

Comment: But it is not usefull for me.It only post the video not the text